# How to copy an empty string to a file

Tags: string, perl, file

I have written a perl script where in some cases I will have to copy an empty string into a file.
For example, `$str` is a variable which contains the number of rows in a MySQL table.
Suppose if there are no rows in the table, empty string is copied to the variable `$str`. This value stored in `$str` needs to be copied to another file. How can I do this?
When I tried to copy I got this warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value $str in string at test.pl line 23
```

Comment: Is this a philosophical question? How do you print the empty string?

Comment: @TLP I'm stuck with this problem, wherein I need to copy the number of rows in a table. If there are no rows it gives an empty set, i.e an empty string. How can I find a solution for this .

Comment: You are only saying half a thing: If there are no rows, then what? How can you find a solution for printing the empty string? You can't, because the empty string cannot be printed. What you *might* be wanting is to print `0` instead, or print `No rows found`, or some other solution, but unless you say what you want, well, its hard to tell you what you want except to guess.

Comment: I wonder if you do not have some kind of bug in your DBI if you are getting a count of rows as `undef` instead of `0`, though.

Comment: @TLP You say it is a bug in DBI

Comment: No. That would be unlikely. I'm saying you probably did not use the DBI module correctly if you get a count as undef.

Comment: @TLP What change would you suggest, can you please tell me

Comment: Since I do not know what your DBI code looks like, it is impossible for me to tell you how to change it. I am just making the assumption that undef is an inappropriate value. You'd need to ask a new question and include the relevant code and errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difference between an empty string (`''`, `""`, or `q()`) and an undefined value (`undef`). Only the last one triggers the warning you mentioned.

If the number of rows should be saved, save 0 in this case:

```
$str //= 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are only worried about the warning? If you have this statement or similar:

```
print $str;
```

And you get the above mentioned warning, it is because `$str` contains the undef value. The `undef` value will be converted to the empty string in this statement, so you can do this:

```
print $str // "";   # defined or operator
```

Do note that this is a way to *hide* the warning, so never do this if an undefined value in `$str` is an indication that something is wrong.

I would think that if you are trying to get a count of rows from `DBI` and you get the `undef` value instead of zero `0`, *then you are doing something wrong, and you should look at your DBI code and search for the problem there.*

If you are certain that `undef` means zero `0`, you can perform an explicit conversion:

```
$str += 0;          # undef is converted to 0
```

Note that this only works with undef. You may use the defined-or assignment operator as well:

```
$str //= 0;
```

If your perl version is too low, you may use the somewhat similar statement in this case:

```
$str ||= 0;
```

Which works if `$str` contains any false value.